# Auto detecting Baud Rate of Arduino

Tags: c#, arduino, baud-rate

I'm trying to detect baud rate of Arduino Mega2560 by using C#. My code is below:

```
SerialPort SP=new SerialPort();
SP.BaudRate = 115200;
```

BaudRate is specified as a constant like this, but I would like to automatically detect it.

For instance, if Arduino code includes Serial.begin(xxxx), program should declare SP.BaudRate = xxxx.

How can I do it?

Comment: check this link: http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php/topic,38160.0.html

Comment: I checked it already, but it's arduino C code for detecting computer's communication baud rate. I want opposite.

Comment: The device has to co-operate and send a predictable byte pattern repeatedly until it gets a command to stop sending them.  So the receiver has a shot at detecting that it gets the wrong bytes and can try a different baudrate.  This is generally unpractical, especially so for Arduino since it doesn't implement the hardware handshake signals so has no way to know that a receiver started listening.  You could only do it from a power-up.